# Error inyectar Controller Net Core 2.2 Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar estoy realizando un web api con net core y inyección de dependencias, estoy realizando con repositorios y UnitOfWork

Bueno el problema es cuando inyecto y lo coloco como constructor el controller

Pero al momento de ejecutar me sale status 500

**Codigo Controller Login**

```
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly IvitaliciaRepository _vitalicia;
   public LoginController (IvitaliciaRepository vitalicia)
{
_vitalicia= vitalicia;
}

[HttpPost]
public void GetProfile([FromBody] string codusuario)
{
  int codigo= _vitalicia.Intcodigo(codusuario);
}

}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{

  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
   Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get;}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddScoped<IvitaliciaRepository,VitaliciaRepository>();
 services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork>(
                new 
                ApplicationUnitOfWork(Configuration
                                        .GetConnectionString("Northwind"))
                );

 services.AddMvc();

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors(option=>
            {
                option.AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
            app.UseMvc();

        }


}
```

Tengo 4 carpetas que son las siguientes.

```
1.ApplicationLayer
  1.1 consultas.DTO
2.CrossCuting
  2.1 Consultas.CrossCuting
3.Domain
  3.1 consultas.entity
4.Infraestructura
  4.1 Consultas.Repository
  4.2 Consultas.UnitOfWork
5. RestService
  5.1 webapi
```

5.Web Api tengo un controllador llamado LoginController.cs donde le quiero inyectar

```
public class LoginController : ApiController
{
  private readonly IVitaliciaRepository _vitalicia;

  public LoginController( IVitaliciaRepository vitalicia)
  {
     _vitalicia= vitalicia;
  }

   [HTTPGET]
   public void get_profile(string nombre)
   {
     int codigo = _vitalicia.intcodigo(nombre);
   }
}
```

4. UnitOfWork tiene 2 clases que son IunitOfWork y UnitOfWork

   En IUnitOfWork

   ```
   public interface IunitOfWork : IDisposable
   {
      IVitalicia vitalicia {get;}
   }
   ```

   y en la clase UnitOfWork

   ```
   public clas UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
   {

     public Ivitalicia vitalicia { get;private set;}
     public UnitOfWork(string cnx) 
     {
          vitalicia = new Vitaliciarepository(cnx);
     }

   }
   ```

   4.1 Consultas.Repository carpeta vitalicia hay una interface y clase de vitalicia

   ```
   public interface IvitaliciaRepository : IGenericRepository<vitalicia>
   {
       int intcodigo(string cnx);
   }
   ```

en la clase vitalicia

```
public vitaliciarepository(string cnx) : base(cnx){}

public int intcodigo(string usario)
{
-------------------------
-----------
}
```

**Error que me sale**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería útil saber qué error estás recibiendo. Error 500 es un error interno del servidor lo cual significa que hay algún problema en tu lógica, pero no creo que podamos ayudarte mucho sin saber específicamente qué problema tienes?

Comment: No hay suficiente informacion sube mas codigo, de tus metodos secundarios

Comment: @MiguelZarate  listo

Comment: Pues en ultima instancia sera necesario que subas tu codigo a alguna instancia para hacer una prueba por el momento note que te falta     services.AddMvc()
                    .AddControllersAsServices();

Comment: @MiguelZarate sale el mismo problema ,

Comment: Crees que puedas subir todo tu codigo a algun repositorio, con valores de configuracion de prueba, envia la liga publica y luego das de baja el repositorio despues de solucionarlo.

Comment: Claro @MiguelZarate ahorita lo adjunto

Comment: @MiguelZarate listo ya subi las imagenes

Comment: Piero.. no se si esto esta bien.. lo vi varias veces. Vos inyectas clases, y lo haces pasando la interfaz de las clases. en tu caso, estas tratando de inyectar una clase ya instanciada. No deberia la clase de conexion hacer la conexion, y solo pasarle a las otras esa clase? no una nueva clase, sino la interfaz de la clase...

Comment: Es bastante confuso, pero leyendo el error me parece que el problema está en que al inyectar la clase que tiene una dependencia `string` (`public vitaliciarepository(string cnx) : base(cnx){}`) el framework de DI no sabe qué valor asignarle a ese parámetro.

Answer (score 7):

Intenta agregar el servicio manualmente, parece que no esta resolviendo la el parametro conexion:

en lugar de

```
  services.AddScoped<IvitaliciaRepository,VitaliciaRepository>();
```

usa

```
services.AddScoped<IvitaliciaRepository>(_ => new VitaliciaRepository("conexion aqui"));
```

Comment: una consulta yo en mi UnitOFwORK tengo todos los repositorio ahora como podria hacer para que un repositorio tenga otro connectionString

Comment: eso es otra pregunta agregala, basicamente solo estas declarando dos repositorios. services.AddDbContext

Comment: yo o hice como me pusiste en la respuesta pero nada

Comment: coloque imagen en  mi pregunta las 2 ultimas fotos

Comment: Me referia a que subieses tu proyecto o un miniproyecto con replicando el problema y lo compartieras mediante un repositorio como Git para descargarlo resorverlo y subir la solucion.

Answer (score 4):

Te comento como lo tengo yo con EntityFramework en la parte Startup.cs a ver si te puede ayudar.

```
services.AddDbContext<AplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

  services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)

services.AddScoped<IVitaliciaRepository, VitaliciaRepository>();
```

y en la parte del modelo de datos:

```
public partial class AplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public AplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<AplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }
}
```